# How can I serve an html file with WSL2 that allows for hot reload (refresh on save) in the browser?

Tags: html, wsl-2, hot-reload

My program produces a single html file; I want to have my browser automatically refresh on save.  I am coding in WSL with Neovim.  I am viewing the file in my windows chrome browser with wslview.  I am open to using other tools to serve the file, but I am looking for a minimalist solution.

As a workaround, I add a `<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3\" >` tag to tell the browser to autorefresh.  This does a decent job but causes excessive refresh and unwanted flickering.  Is there a more intelligent way to open the html file and truly refresh on save?

Comment: You'll need to include some javascript on the page to connect to the server and query for changes, then reload the page programmatically from the client side. The server cannot tell the client to reload the page without the client running some cooperating javascript.

Comment: Would hope to avoid javascript in the page, I just have a static html file at the moment.  I was imagining an experience like VSCode Live Server from the command line.

Comment: Sorry, you can't avoid a client-side refresh.